# Mysterious behaviour of static_cast

Tags: c++, qt, operators, static-cast

I am trying to implement a class of numeric vectors. I am using Qt template QVector which is similar to the STL vector

```
typedef float ArithmeticF;
typedef QVector<ArithmeticF> VectorFloat;

class VectorF : public VectorFloat
{
/// appends the rightSide to the end
VectorF& operator << (const VectorF& rightSide);
}
```

The thing that confuses me is that

```
VectorF& VectorF::operator << (const VectorF& rightSide)
{
static_cast<VectorFloat>(*this) <<  static_cast<VectorFloat>(rightSide);
return *this;
}
```

does not work at all. I tried to debug it line by line and the VectorFloat::operator<< does not get called at all. There are no errors, the program compiles and runs, but does nothing. However this works:

```
VectorF& VectorF::operator << (const VectorF& rightSide)
{
VectorFloat a = static_cast<VectorFloat>(*this);
VectorFloat b = static_cast<VectorFloat>(rightSide);
a << b;
*this = VectorF(a);
return *this;
}
```

I am just curious why is it so. I tried to dig into the static_cast command, but I cannot figure it out.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting to the value type `VectorFloat`, which makes a copy of your `*this` object and applies the `<<` operator to it. This temporary object gets promptly destroyed and thus nothing of effect could be observed.

You should cast to the reference `VectorFloat&` instead:

```
static_cast<VectorFloat&>(*this) <<  static_cast<VectorFloat>(rightSide);
```

The fact that second example works is easily explicable. You are storing the copied object in `a` variable, and you are reconstructing your `VectorF` based on this modified copy. There are WAY too many operations being done along the way (conversion to `VectorFloat`, converting back to `VectorF`, assignment to `*this`), but in practice it works.

Comment: It is customary to click the "tick" next to an answer if it was the most helpful one for you :) In any case, glad I could help!